# Difficulty with unmarshalling in parcelable

Tags: android, unmarshalling, parcelable, runtimeexception

Here is my code of writing to a parcel

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(poiDescription);
        dest.writeString(latitude);
        dest.writeString(longitude);
        dest.writeString(placeName);
        dest.writeString(plistPath);
        dest.writeString(poiDirName);
            if (null != isMascotPresent)
                dest.writeString(isMascotPresent);
            if (null != startMascottTime)
                dest.writeInt(startMascottTime);
            if (null != mascottDuration)
                dest.writeInt(mascottDuration);
}

public PointOfInterest(Parcel source) { 
        poiDescription = source.readString();
        latitude = source.readString();
        longitude = source.readString();
        placeName = source.readString();
        plistPath = source.readString();
        poiDirName = source.readString();
        audioLinkDownload = source.readString();
        audioLinkStream = source.readString();
        poiName = source.readString();
        poiIndex = source.readInt();
        poiPaused = source.readString();
        source.readList(imageList, null);
        source.readList(durationList, null);
        if (null != isMascotPresent)
            isMascotPresent = source.readString();
        if (null != startMascottTime)
               startMascottTime=source.readInt();
        if (null != mascottDuration)
                  mascottDuration=source.readInt();
}


This is how I am reading the values
listOfPOI = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("poi");
```

This codw works fine without the mascot above.

But when I add those 3 lines about mascot, my application is crashing. I am breaking my head onthis, I am not getting why is this happening, can anyone please let me know the issue?

I am getting the run time exception and problem saying there is unmarshalling error for the parcelable

This is the exception I am getting

```
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity       ComponentInfo{com.Invenger/com.Invenger.Player.Audio}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@40570848: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7536748 at offset 1064
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@40570848: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7536748 at offset 1064
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1913)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2092)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1536)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1867)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2083)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at   android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:1144)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.content.Intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.java:3448)
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at com.Invenger.Player.Audio.onCreate(Audio.java:162)
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2061):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is the type of `isMascotPresent`?

Comment: isMascotPresent is of type String

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I fixed the problem somehow. I made it as static instead of making it parcelable.Ihis may not be the standard way, of making it static. But I feel that there is a limit on the size of parcel. If I add  some 15 or more variable it is not working. So it is working for me now.

Any better answer will be accepted

Comment: Parcels by themselves do not have limits, and they are very efficient. The issue of size arises when transferring them across processes with AIDL. 2MB is a hard limit on any IPC transaction. Not working with 15+ variables might just be a matter of optional variables not taken care of properly, or placing the read/write calls in the wrong order.

Comment: Try killing your process while activity is in the background and then coming back to it. Statics is not always an option. Entire idea of parcelables is ability to persist the object across the processes (or persist it while your process is dead).

Comment: @PaulTurchenko, first of all thank you for answering. But there was no need for you to downvote my answer. I had clearly mentioned any better answer will be accepted. I had written what I had done. When ever you down vote, please see the effort also and think before you ink!

Comment: I'm also down-voting because anyone searching this problem should not do this to avoid it.  @Johnbot's answer above is correct.

Answer (score 12):

Unless you're initializing `isMascotPresent`, `startMascottTime` and `mascottDuration` somewhere they're always going to be `null` in the constructor, `PointOfInterest(Parcel source)`. So even if you wrote values when parceling the object they wouldn't be read and the following values would be incorrect.

Instead of checking if they're `null` when reading/writing the mascot info you could use a `boolean`:

```
    if (null != isMascotPresent) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 1);
        dest.writeString(isMascotPresent);
        dest.writeInt(startMascottTime);
        dest.writeInt(mascottDuration);
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) 0);
    }
```

And to read it back in:

```
    if(source.readByte() == 1) {
        isMascotPresent = source.readString();
        startMascottTime = source.readInt();
        mascottDuration = source.readInt();
    } else {
        isMascotPresent = null;
        startMascottTime = null;
        mascottDuration = null;
    }
```

And you're also reading more values in than you're writing out to the parcel. Values need to be written and read in the same order.

Comment: I am setting the values for these in other place, so do I need to initialize them to null or empty character?  I think no, right?  Anyways, I will try this soon and will let you know the result. Thanks

Comment: The only place where you can set the values before the constructor is at the declaration: 'String isMascotPresent;' and 'String isMascotPresent = null;' means it'll always be null in the constructor. 'String isMascotPresent = "something";' means it'll always be non-null in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was actually doing the null-check and catching exception, but this is a MUCH better idea! Better to not throw the exceptions at all an use a simple byte to store whether or not optional values are present.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android studio plugin, which generates Android Parcelable boilerplate code for you.
File->Settings->Plugins->Browse Repositories->search for Android Parcelable code generator.
OR
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7332?pr=

Problem is in sequence of writing and reading of object...sequence should be same, as it is like reading file.