# Parcelable class with many possible null values

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I have a parcelable class which looks something like this:

```
public class Product implements Parcelable {
    private String name;
    private String ean;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String description;
    private String safetyText;
    private String width;
    private String height;
    private String weight;
    private String length;
    private String youtubeId;
    private String ageFrom;
    private String ageTo;
}
```

As you can see, there are many different properties and the thing is that most of them can be `null`. This class is populated by `json` parser that parses data provided by server. And the data may be incomplete.

I know the trick when a `1/0` byte is put to parcel before the actual string and when I'm reading from the parcel I can use this byte to indicate whether the String value is present or not. But it's not a very good solution for 12+ Strings, the code would get really messy. Is there any more elegant solution?

Comment: If you don't initialize then they will remain `null` and `1/0` will throw `ArithmeticException`. I think you need to reword clearly.

Comment: I was referring to this trick http://stackoverflow.com/a/7512901/576997 when a 1/0 byte is put to parcel first and when I'm reading from the parcel I can use this byte to check whether the following value is present or not. But you're right, it's not clear, I'll try to rephrase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `Parcel.writeString()` will handle null values just fine. The corresponding `Parcel.readString()` will return null as expected.

The only thing important is to match the order and type of the reads with the writes.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, I've just tested it. Even the Array version handles null values as expected. I worked with some general objects before and they had to be treated with the 1/0 byte. I just assumed that it applied to Strings as well.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no distinction in your code between and empty string and a null pointer to a string (and it's good if there isn't a distinction), one possible answer is to just initialize all Strings to an empty String in your constructor or your parser.  Then you'll always be able to assume the String exists when you're parcelling.

Answer (score 0):

there is a much easier solution, in your parsing of the json, check first if the data is provided, if so then it's all good,

and if not then pass `0`  as the value, seeing that you work with strings that will be used as Integers later,

hope this helps